# Basic function call doesn't work

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

RESOLVED: Check my reply for solution.

I am using truffle and ganache to make a simple call to my smart contract. I enter into truffle console and I'm running into issues calling a very simple function. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to call getValue()

[image: Code Snipped]

In truffle console I do:

```
let chx = await PillowChecking.deployed()
```

When I try the following:

```
let a = chx.getValue()
```

I get this error

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction:
> revert\n

NOTE: I can define new addresses all day long and it does not crash. For example this works just fine:

```
let address = chx.getAddress()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to you at some point I needed to redeploy my contracts. I used `truffle deploy --reset` and my functions worked after that.